# lassign of array shows double the number of columns than exists in TCL

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have one 2D array called "jb_node" and it has 74 columns for row no. 274.

```
set jb_column [llength [array names jb_node 274,*]
puts "The row 274 has $jb_column"
puts $jb_code(274,75)
```

First puts options shows me the column numbers are 148, but the second puts shows the error.

I have written temp file in between the flow and confirmed that number of columns are actually 74.
why lassign statements shows double the columns. Any hint ?

BR,
SemiCode

Comment: Try printing the sorted names (`lsort -dictionary` is ideal) and seeing if there are any unexpected names in there.

Comment: Can't really reproduce what you are describing. You also seem to have a typo on the first line, there should be 2 `]` instead of a single one at the end. Can you show how you are checking that the actual number of columns is 74? Maybe there are columns that are not numbered 1-74, but more like 101-174 (or something along those lines, it's hard to tell without seeing the data)

Comment: @Jerry I was assuming that was a typo when writing the question. No way the code works without it.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes I think so too, just want to have everything correct in the question before making too many false assumptions.

Comment: @Jerry My mistake.I figure out that I did not reset the array for jb_node, though others were done. therefore the the array size became double but the content still shows from 274,1 .. 274,74.

Comment: There are no issues then? Going to vote to close the question as not reproducible if so, because there can't be a solution to a problem that doesn't exist :)

Comment: Did any of the answers to your last question help? If so, you should mark it as accepted.